# API KEY: Reinsertion Cointop via Brew on macOS

Tags: debugging, key, patch, insertion

error inputting api key into cointop.sh.

I say "installing $: cointop
FATA[0000] Near line 80 (last key parsed 'coinmarketcap.pro_api_key'): unexpected EOF"

I need to put back in the proper API key as i goofed up the system,
I have deleted cointop from brew and reran the cointop but unfortently
i get the error below:

```
FATA[0000] Near line 80 (last key parsed 'coinmarketcap.pro_api_key'): unexpected EOF``

<code>

cointop
FATA[0000] Near line 80 (last key parsed 'coinmarketcap.pro_api_key'): unexpected EOF

</code>

I just wanted a simple install script for this but i'm not smart
and wanted to say oops to cointop for this error/fix.
```

Comment: I wasnt cheating the system i was just confused on inserting the api key I have removed cointop and updated brew is there a config file somewhere i need to delete? So i can put in the proper api key from cointop.

Comment: ok so i got cointop running by deleting the config file and reinstalling cointop however i could have edited the default config file with:
[coinmarketcap]    
                           pro_api_key = ""

Answer (score 0):

[cointop](https://github.com/miguelmota/cointop) author here; this might have been fixed in the latest release but if you encounter issues like this even after installing the latest version then you can reset the config with `cointop --reset` (make sure to backup relevant changes first)

Comment: Thanks for the follow up and sorry if this error might have cause more issues or possibly a single isolated instance.